# MySQL fail to order list of rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm pretty much a noob in SQL subqueries, and I can't figure out why is mysql not sorting my query as requested.

```
SELECT
    thread.id,
    thread.views,
    (
        SELECT forum_posts.dateline
        FROM forum_posts
        WHERE forum_posts.threadID = thread.id
        ORDER BY forum_posts.id DESC LIMIT 1
    ) AS last_reply
FROM 
    forum_threads thread,
    forum_posts
WHERE
    thread.forumID = 7
    AND thread.language = 'ro'
ORDER BY last_reply DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

If I remove the AS from the subquery it returns the query as it should but it doesn't sort the resulted rows. If I keep the AS it returns the first result times the number of posts in the database.

Any idea ? Finally what I am trying to accomplish is getting the last post dateline for every thread, instead just updating it in mysql everytime someone posts.

Comment: what's the type of forum_posts.dateline? If it's a varchar and you're storing wonky date formats like `mm/dd/yy`, you're going to get STRING ordering of the dates, not actual calendar ordering. If you were storing actual mysql date/datetime values, e.g. yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, you'd get proper date/time sorting.

Comment: @MarcB it's an INT(10) i store the unix_timestamp there.

Comment: using a select as a field can be very slow.  consider rewriting this as a self join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your problem is the unnecessary join in the outer query to `forum_posts`.  This seems closer to what you want:

```
SELECT thread.id, thread.views,
       (SELECT forum_posts.dateline
        FROM forum_posts
        WHERE forum_posts.threadID = thread.id
        ORDER BY forum_posts.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS last_reply
FROM forum_threads thread
WHERE thread.forumID = 7 AND thread.language = 'ro'
ORDER BY last_reply DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```